# How to add two lines at the beginning of multiple files?

Tags: bash

Why does the following file does not work?

```
for f in H_*.dat; do
    echo -e "Exported\nOm\n" >> "$f"
done
```

The result is that the two extra lines are after the file.

Desired result

```
Exported
Om
file H_*
```

Comment: Can you add the actual result? Just eyeballing it it looks like you aren't adding the filename for the file, and have some unnecessary whitespace. You probably need to change the echo statement to `echo -e "Exported\nOm\n$f"`

Comment: There's a question on the Superuser StackExchange (with some good answers) that might help you https://superuser.com/q/246837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sed:

```sh
sed -i '1i\
Exported\
0m
' H_*.dat
```

where `i` is the [insert](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-i-_0028insert-text-lines_0029-command) command, and the `-i` option replaces the files in-place.

Answer (score 3):

> How to add two lines at the beginning of multiple files?

Iterate over the files, as you do. Inside the loop, group the statements together and redirect their output together. Use a temporary file (or `sponge`).

```
{
    echo Exported
    echo Om
    cat "$f"
} > "$f.tmp" 
mv "$f.tmp" "$f"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ed](/questions/tagged/ed) to edit the files in-place

```sh
ed "$f" <<END_ED
0i
Exported
0m
.
wq
END_ED
```

`.` tells ed to stop insert mode.

Comment: `wq` is a GNU ed extension; if using another version, just `w`. It'll quit automatically at EOF on standard input. I usually use the `-s` option too to prevent spam about file size getting printed out.

Comment: I tend to use `0a` instead of `0i` , It's just an old habit since the latter will fail on empty files, not that if is an issue here but just saying.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `cat` just like what @KamiCuk did but with the `stdin` flag which is a `-`

```
for f in H_*.dat; do
   printf '%s\n' Exported Om | cat - "$f" > "$f.tmp" && mv "$f.tmp" "$f"
done
```

See [How do I create a temporary file in a secure manner](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/062) If `"$f.tmp"` is not good enough for some security reasons.

Also `mv` will break symbolic links jfyi.